# How to get scroll on the body to scroll a sidebar like Airbnb?

Tags: javascript, html, css, scroll, custom-scrolling

So I have a layout that is very similar to Airbnb's search layout, but I haven't been able to replicate their scrolling behaviour. When you scroll on their site, the scroll first moves the left column and the map element remains fixed, but when you reach the end ofn the column then everything moves and you reach the footer. I've been researching but haven't been able to find any methods to replicate such behaviour.
[My site](https://divot.now.sh), [Airbnb site](https://www.airbnb.com/s/Cairns--Queensland/homes?adults=0&children=0&infants=0&place_id=ChIJEySiW1VieGkRYHggf_HuAAQ&refinement_paths%5B%5D=%2Fhomes&search_type=unknown).

Answer (score -1):

On the right side container element you need to put `position: fixed`. and the body element should be smaller height or put `overflow:hidden` to hide scroll bar of the whole page.